# Matlab 7.5 (2007b) Calling superclass function in overloaded subclass

Tags: matlab, overloading

When I call

```
p = inputParser2;
addRequired(p, 'A');
```

in Matlab 7.5 (2007b), with

```
classdef inputParser2 < inputParser
  methods
    function addRequired(obj, argname, varargin)
      addRequired@inputParser(obj, argname);
    end
  end
end
```

I get the error message

```
??? Error using ==> mcos_parent_function_
addRequired is not a method of base class inputParser.

Error in ==> inputParser2>inputParser2.addRequired at 5
      addRequired@inputParser(obj, argname);
```

But `addRequired` is clearly a method of class `inputParser`?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue with Matlab 2013b

Comment: Yes me neither, this issue occured in Matlab 2007b. They have a mixture there between old and new class definitions and it appears that `inputParser` is defined in the new classdef syntax.